# State a function such that $f'(0)$ exists but limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $f'(x)$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I had a test in real analysis today and could not think of an example that fit these parameters. Just trying to settle my curiosity, since googling didn't turn up anything.

Comment: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = 0\\ x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x^2} &, x \neq 0.\end{cases}$$ I'm sure it has been asked before, let me search.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256905/let-fx-x2-sin-1-x2-x-ne-0-and-f0-0-prove-f-is-differentiab) is a proof.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865028/is-it-differentiable/) also.

Comment: [I asked a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/386967/76987) where [one of the answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/386977/76987) gave Daniel Fischer's example of a function that is continuous yet has a discontinuous derivative.

Comment: Another example: Let $g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}\sin(1/x),&\mbox{ if }x\ne0\\ 0&\mbox{ if }x=0.\end{array}\right.$ This function *is* a derivative. So its antiderivative $f$ is an example.

Comment: Is that really "another" example, or essentially the same example?